# Better to put interrupting phrase before or after that-conjunction?

Tags: commas, sentence, conjunctions, complex-sentences, interrupting-phrase

Which sentence is either correct or better than the other? Are they both valid?

1. Then she eagerly dug into every basket and confirmed **that, to her pleasant surprise**, they were all loaded with good apples hidden under the bad.
2. Then she eagerly dug into every basket and confirmed, **to her pleasant surprise, that** they were all loaded with good apples hidden under the bad.

Comment: Both are common. There may be some people who prefer one to the other, and are probably some situations where one is neater than the other (e.g. if the parenthetical phrase also starts with "that"). But I think you can do what you like.

Comment: I'd put the parenthetical before 'confirmed' here. But then I'd probably use 'discovered'.

Comment: I think pedants would complain that in #2 the pleasant surprise is the confirmation, not what was confirmed. But in casual usage, they're equivalent.